# Trying to call this method in my view and pass the input to the method argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, view, simple-form

Here is my method in my user controller:

```
  def donation_custom(amount)
   @user = current_user
   @user.amount_donated += amount
   @user.save
   redirect_to root_path, :alert => "thanks for donating" 
  end
```

I just need a simple input form in my view so i can call this method and pass the user input to my "amount" argument.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just stick with the RESTful way of doing this? Create a custom setter method in your User model:

```
validates :add_amount, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0}

def add_amount=(value)
  self.amount_donated += value
end
```

then create a simple form that captures this:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  Amount to donate <%= f.text_field :add_amount %><br>
  <%= f.submit "Donate!" %>
<% end %>
```

and then use your `UsersController#update` method to set this:

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  # you'll probably want to add some error checking here
  @user.update_attributes(user_params)
  redirect_to root_path, notice: "Thanks for donating!"
end

private

def user_params
  # you'll probably want to whitelist other parameters here
  params.require(:user).permit(:add_amount)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not recommending this as a general approach to this problem, and there are other issues in your code that I'm not pointing out, but your request is so specific that you're obviously just looking for a specific solution to this problem, so...

Remove the args from the method signature, all form parameters are presented to controllers as a hash called `params`, so your method should become:

```
def donation_custom
  @user = current_user
  @user.amount_donated += params[:amount]
  @user.save
  redirect_to root_path, :alert => "thanks for donating" 
end
```

And then in your view you will have something like this:

```
<%= form_tag '/your_controller/donation_custom' do -%>
  <div><%= text_field_tag :amount %></div>
  <div><%= submit_tag 'Save' %></div>
<% end -%>
```

Answer (score 0):

The form_for helper accepts a parameter called **url** and here you should use the route helper of that controller **donate_custom_path** and then instead of doing

```
@user.amount_donated = amount
```

You do

```
@user.amount_donated = params[:amount]
```

And you leave the donation_custom with 0 parameters